# highchart place x-axis labels in between ticks on a datetime axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, data-visualization, axis-labels

Using various posts/questions in SO as reference I created a scatter highchart [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damseldeebi/td14sgyz/6/)

```
xAxis: {
        opposite:true,
        type: 'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'ShortDot',
        gridLineColor:'black',
        alternateGridColor: 'lightgrey',
        tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // 1 quarter
        labels: {
            //align: "left",
            //padding:200,
            formatter: function () {
                var s = "";
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jan') {
                    s = s + "Q1"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Apr') {
                    s = s + "Q2"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jul') {
                    s = s + "Q3"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Oct') {
                    s = s + "Q4"
                };
                s = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
                return s;
            }
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red', // Color value
            value: now, // Value of where the line will appear
            width: 2, // Width of the line
            label: {
                text: 'Now',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                y: +20,
                rotation: 0
            }
        }]
    },
```

But I'm struck with having the X-axis label positioned near the tick.
How to move to middle of the grid?

[image: existing chart]

Is there anyway I can achieve the below? [image: expected result]

I tried **align, padding** but didn't help. When the timeline increases I should still have the labels positioned in the middle.
should I do something with **tickInterval**? It might be a simple property I'm missing.

I found this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/p0a128uq/5/) which addresses my concern but with 2 x-axis and I'm populating the data from a list.

Comment: With a category axis, you can use 'tickMarkPlacement:between'. But since you are using a datetime axis, your only option may be to set the 'x' property of the labels, and push them to the right or left

Comment: e.g. - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/td14sgyz/8/

Answer (score 1):

I implemented Christopher Cortez' solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516321/2374028):

[image]

However, also changed to to fire on the highcharts `load` event, rather than the callback, and I've changed it to be recalled when the HighCharts `redraw` event is fired, so that they stay aligned when the page is resized.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            defaultSeriesType: 'scatter',
            events: {
                 load: centerLabels,
                 redraw: centerLabels                    
            }
        },

        /* ... all the other options ...*/

 });
```

Where

```
function centerLabels(chart) {        
    var $container = $(chart.target.container); 
    var axes = chart.target.axes;

    var $labels = $container.find('.highcharts-axis-labels .timeline_label');
    var $thisLabel, $nextLabel, thisXPos, nextXPos, delta, newXPos;

    $labels.each(function () {
        $thisLabel = $(this).parent('span');
        thisXPos = parseInt($thisLabel.css('left'));

        $nextLabel = $thisLabel.next();
        // next position is either a label or the end of the axis
        nextXPos = $nextLabel.length ? parseInt($nextLabel.css('left')) : axes[0].left + axes[0].width;
        delta = (nextXPos - thisXPos) / 2.0;
        newXPos = thisXPos + delta;

        // remove the last label if it won't fit
        if ($nextLabel.length || $(this).width() + newXPos < nextXPos) {
            $thisLabel.css('left', newXPos + 'px');
        } else {
            $thisLabel.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/td14sgyz/12/)

Comment: It works. but when I try to _export_ the labels are not aligned in the middle.

Comment: Try to use [load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) instead of callback.

Comment: That's a good idea, much cleaner. I edited my answer. However, it still doesn't solve the exporting problem.